# Flag to switch off tearing in Dymola

Tags: dymola

Is there a (hidden) flag, or any other way, to switch off the tearing algorithm in Dymola (2016 FD01).

I know, that there is a flag called `Hidden.UseNewTearing`, but I am not able to find any further hidden flags related to the tearing step.

Answer (score 2):

No, that was removed with Dymola 5.3 a dozen years ago.
But more importantly - you should probably explain why you want to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I run into problems with the translation of large systems (>100 000 eq., most of them simple) that include a linear equation system of size ~1000. The translation eats all the memory (32gb) and fails. As, to my best knowledge, Matching and Sorting do not grow that dramatically with the size of the model, I though that Tearing is the problem. Anyway, I solved the problem by hiding the linear equations from the model by using an external c-function and the [Eigen Library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). Not the best solution, but ok.....

Comment: There are some possible explanations for that - not necessarily to the tearing - it would help if you could provide the example. Some have also been corrected after Dymola 2016 FD01.